# LINQ grouping multiple fields and placing non-unique fields into list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects, `TargetList` populated from the database which I want to group together based on the `AnalyteID`, `MethodID` and `InstrumentID` fields, but the `Unit` fields will be stored in a list applicable to each grouped object.

Furthermore, it is only possible for one of the available units to have a target assigned to it.  Therefore, during the grouping I need a check to see if a target is available and, if so, skip creation of the unit list.

[image: Database extraction of targets]

The `TargetList` object contains the following attributes:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public int AnalyteID { get; set; }
public string AnalyteName { get; set; }
public int MethodID { get; set; }
public string MethodName { get; set; }
public int InstrumentID { get; set; }
public string InstrumentName { get; set; }
public int UnitID { get; set; }
public string UnitDescription { get; set; }
public decimal TargetMean { get; set; }
public List<Unit> Units { get; set; }
```

I have a method for multi-grouping using LINQ:

```
TargetList.GroupBy(x => new { x.AnalyteID, x.MethodID, x.InstrumentID })...
```

But unsure as to how to check for a target at a row before extracting all available units at current group if target doesn't exist.

Comment: Grouping is fine, projected data will be of type `Target`, but what do you need post it, you can flatten the `Units` using `SelectMany` if required

Comment: I couldn't understand well what you meant. What is the 'target'. A row means 'target' ?

Comment: Each row returned is effectively a `Target` object. Any `Target` with an assigned `TargetMean` will only ever return one row (as only one unit can be assigned to a `Target`. However, if no `TargetMean` is available the SP returns as many rows as there are `UnitID`'s for that analyte/method/instrument combination. Therefore I need to group the returned rows and split out all available units (for each target combination with no `TargetMean`) and place them into a list. I hope this is a little clearer.

Comment: @Sandman As I see the `TargetMean` is not a nullable type. It will be set default value as zero but `null`. Are you aware of this situation ?

Comment: @sinanakyazici Yes I am aware of this. 0 is used as a placeholder for `TargetMean` values to be entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a solution which groups all rows returned from the database based on the `AnalyteID`, `MethodID` and `InstrumentID` ('names' of each of these are included in the grouping aswell).

Additionally, all non-unique `Unit` attributes (`UnitID` and `UnitDescription`) are placed into a list only if the `TargetMean` is 0.

```
targetViewModel.TargetList                      
    // Group by unique analyte/method/instrument   
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.AnalyteID, x.AnalyteName, x.MethodID, x.MethodName, x.InstrumentID, x.InstrumentName }) 
        // Select all attributes and collect units together in a list                   
        .Select(g => new TargetView
        {
            id = g.Max(i => i.id),
            AnalyteID = g.Key.AnalyteID,
            AnalyteName = g.Key.AnalyteName,
            MethodID = g.Key.MethodID,
            MethodName = g.Key.MethodName,
            InstrumentID = g.Key.InstrumentID,  
            InstrumentName = g.Key.InstrumentName,
            TargetMean = g.Max(i => i.TargetMean),
            UnitID = g.Max(i => i.UnitID),
            UnitDescription = g.Max(i => i.UnitDescription),
            // only extract units when target mean is 0                   
            Units = g.Where(y => y.TargetMean == 0) 
                .Select(c => new Unit { ID = c.UnitID, Description = c.UnitDescription }).ToList() 
}).ToList();
```

Note: The `Max` method is used to extract any required non-key attributes, such as the `TargetMean`/`id`.  This works fine because only one row will ever be returned if a `TargetMean` exists.

It does feel 'dirty' to use the `Max` method in order to obtain all other non-key attributes though so if anyone has any other suggestions, please feel free to drop an answer/comment as I am interested to see if there are any cleaner ways of achieving the same result.